# Eclipse editor show strange characters

Tags: eclipse

I am coding using Eclipse IDE.

For last few days,I see strange characters in the editor, as shown in pic below.

[image]

Any idea how to get rid of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General > Editors > Text Editors > Show whitespace characters = off

Reference: http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-texteditorprefs.htm

Please let me know if it help.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Mandroid  Can you also accept it?  It is my first answer for this forum XD.